# error in redirecting page code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

I'm developing a web with CodeIgniter framework. I'm new in this kind of work. I got a problem when redirecting page after submit a data form. I want to redirect to that form page (that named **detaillaporan**) again after submit button is clicked. But all i got was

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: laporan
Filename: home/detaillaporan.php
```

Here are some codes in my **controller**:

```
public function detailLaporan($kode_laporan)
{
    $data['page']='detaillaporan';
    $data['laporan'] = $this->Home_model->getLapDetail($kode_laporan);
    $data['id'] = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $data['respon'] = $this->Home_model->getResponInfo($kode_laporan)->result_array();
    $data['rsp'] = $this->Home_model->getResponInfo($kode_laporan)->num_rows();
    $data['kode_laporan'] = $this->session->set_userdata('kode_laporan');
    $this->load->view('home/master', $data);
}

public function beriRespon($kode_laporan){
        $data['kode_laporan'] = $kode_laporan;
        $data['id'] = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p style="color:red;">', '</p>');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('isi_respon', 'Tulis Respon..', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $data['page'] = 'detaillaporan';
        $data['kode_laporan'] = $kode_laporan;
        $this->load->view('home/master', $data);
    } else {
        $config['upload_path']    = './assets/img/laporan/';
        $config['allowed_types']  = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['remove_spaces']  = FALSE;

        //load upload library
        $this->load->library('upload' , $config);

        $imgData = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->Home_model->inputRespon($imgData, $data);

        $data['message'] = 'Laporan berhasil dikirim!';
        $data['redir'] = 'laporan/'.$kode_laporan;
        $data['page'] = 'detaillaporan';
        $this->load->view('home/master', $data);
    }

}
```

And here is the code in **"routes.php"**

```
$route['laporan/(:any)']= 'home/detaillaporan/$1';
$route['beri-respon/(:any)'] = 'home/beriRespon/$1';
```

I'm looking forward to get help from you. Thankyou!

Comment: you should use redirect method after insertion of data

Comment: please follow this.  `https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=redirect#redirect`

Comment: @msz it works! thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the method `beriRespon` (presumably where your form submits to) the variable `laporan` was not defined.

Take a cue from your first method (`detailLaporan`) and add:

```
$data['laporan'] = $this->Home_model->getLapDetail($kode_laporan);`
```

before the if/else condition.

If this variable isn't always required surround it in an isset in your view:

```
if (isset($laporan)) {
    print_r($laporan); // or whatever
}
```

this way you won't get undefined errors.